# Image is null after its picked by using image_picker package and saved on local memory (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

Description:
I'm using (image_picker: ^0.8.5+3) package to pick the images from gallery and camera and then upload them on backend server (django by using django rest framework)

Issue:
Image is getting null outside picker function, even though state has been set by using setSatet(() {}) method

Failed Solutions:
I tried to save the image locally before uploading the image on the backend, But image still shown null once its used or referenced outside picker function

Note: backend API's works fine and i can upload images by using postman

picker function:

```
  // Get image from gallery and store it locally
  Future<File?> _getFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile? image = await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) {
      return null;
    }

    final File file = File(image.path);
    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final imagepath = directory.path;
    final String fileName = path.basename(image.path);

    File newImage = await file.copy('$imagepath/$fileName');
    setState(() {
      _imagelocal = newImage;
      print('image.path1');
      print(_imagelocal!.path);
    });
  }
```

Uploading image function:

```
_uploadimage() async {
      Map<String,String> header = {
        "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream)"
      };
      print("uploaded image invoked");
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.15:8000/api/uploadimage'));
      
      // request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile('image',http.ByteStream(image.openRead()).cast(),await image.length(),filename:image.name, contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile('LoadModelImage',http.ByteStream(_imagelocal!.openRead()).cast(),await _imagelocal!.length(),));
      request.headers.addAll(header);
      //for completeing the request
      var response =await request.send();

      //for getting and decoding the response into json format
      var responsed = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
      final responseData = json.decode(responsed.body);


      if (response.statusCode==201) {
        print("SUCCESS");
        print(responseData);
      }
      else {
        print("ERROR");
      }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using android or ios? If it's iOS, please check the installation steps for the image picker here: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Can you please provide more information about the call of the _getFromGallery Function? You defined a return type for the function but you only returning null.

You don't have to save the image on the disk. The `PickedFile image =...` should be enough and is working for me.

Also setState() is not needed if you don't want to rebuild the screen and display new information to the user.

Comment: @mfrischbutter, I need to upload the image in the backend server and thats why I have uploadimage() function, I tried to merge 2 functions in one but when I checked the image on server it was null!!, there is no issue in picker function and I can change it to void one since no return value is needed, but this will not solve the issue of null image,  after long time I figured out that picker function takes some time to upload the image meanwhile uploadimage will be fired and uploads empty image hence I need to add a delay so picker function can take its time before firing uploadimage function

Comment: Hm, you should check the image var using the debugger. You are already awaiting the pickerImage Function, there should be no issue.

Comment: Here i got a small snippet from my code, maybe you find something useful. I'm using readAsBytes() instead ByteStream(). 
https://gist.github.com/mfrischbutter/75c17307c7d59adeb9f7b524952855dc

Comment: @mfrischbutter, Thank for your reply, I solved the issue!! Yes it waits but I called both functions in sequential base inside elevated button and when I checked the logs I found that uploadimage get executed completely before getting the image from picker even though picker is very quick, Other issue was in image filed name in backend doesn't match this one I used in multipartfile.frompath request (typo) , So once I corrected the filed name and moved the upload function from elevated button to setState inside getimagegallery it works!!